# How to mock redis for Django tests

Tags: django, testing, redis

I am trying to mock out redis in my Django application. I have tried several different methods but none seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

My primary redis instance is called with:

```
redis_client = redis.from_url(os.environ.get("REDIS_URL"))
```

That instance is imported in other parts of the app in order to add and retrieve data.

In my tests I tried doing:

```
import fakeredis
from mock import patch

class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        redis_patcher = patch('redis.Redis', fakeredis.FakeRedis)
        self.redis = redis_patcher.start()

        self.redis.set('UPDATE', 'Spring')
        print(redis_client.get('UPDATE'))

    def tearDown(self):
        self.redis_patcher.stop
```

When running the tests I want the 'UPDATE' variable to be set. But instead every instance of redis_client fails saying the server is not available. How can I mock out redis and set values, so that they are available when testing my app?

Comment: I was using Redis via Django's own cache, so I had to just: @mock.patch('django.core.cache.cache.get')

Getting a proper fake Redis going was so hard I decided to quit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should mock an item where it is used, not where it came from.

So if `redis_client` is used in a view like this:

**myapp/views.py**

```
from somemodule import redis_client

def some_view_that_uses_redis(request):
    result = redis_client(...)
```

Then in your `TestViews` you should patch `redis_client` like this:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        redis_patcher = patch('myapp.views.redis_client', fakeredis.FakeRedis)
        self.redis = redis_patcher.start()
```

Comment: This was my issue, thanks. Know of any way to patch multiple views with less code? Right now I have to patch 5 instances or redis_client, with each having its own redis_patcher1.start(), redis_patcher2.start(), etc.

Comment: Perhaps you could drop the stuff going on in `setUp()` and `tearDown()` and patch the whole `TestViews` class with `@patch('myapp.views.redis_client', fakeredis.FakeRedis)`. Each test method would then need to accept an argument to receive the patched `redis`. They could then configure that how they needed it, and delegate any common configuration to a module, or class level, function - e.g. `configure_mock_redis(redis)`.